# ByPass @PreAuthorize on Repository if called programmatically

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-data

I have a spring data repository for managing users whose methods are secured with `@PreAuthorization`.
But I a need to call theese methods programmatically for custom authentication and authorization purposes. Is there any way to restrict springs authorization to http requests only?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the *security facade pattern*. Something like:

```java
@Service
public class SecurityFacade {

    @Autowired
    private userDao;

    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
    public User getUser(String username) {
        return userDao.getUser(username);
    }
}
```

When you need to check for authorization, you go through this service class. When you don't, you call the DAO directly.

Comment: A similiar solution came already to my mind but the drawback is that I need to _proxy_ every method that I want to expose as a rest endpoint. In case of a `org.springframework.data.repository.CurdRepository` that would be 11 methods to proxy if I wanted to expose all default methods.